# LinearLayout Visibility Gone

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Alright, I'm running into a bizarre problem with my Android Layout. I have two LinearLayouts in my xml layout definition. What I want to do is hide them both at the start of the program, and then set the visibility of each of them dynamically at runtime, just showing one at a time.

This is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip" >
    <!-- Unimportant stuff -->
  </LinearLayout>    
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/results1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >
    <SegmentedRadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/segment_sort"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/button_one"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_one"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="33dip"
            android:text="@string/sort_first"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_two"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="33dip"
            android:text="@string/sort_second"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_three"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="33dip"
            android:text="@string/sort_third"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
    </SegmentedRadioGroup>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/results2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <SegmentedRadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/segment_sort2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/button_one2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_one2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="33dip"
            android:text="@string/sort_first"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_two2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="33dip"
            android:text="@string/sort_second"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_three2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="33dip"
            android:text="@string/sort_third"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
    </SegmentedRadioGroup>
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btBottom" />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the problem that I'm having is that even though both visibilities are set to "gone",
the second LinearLayout, results2, is always shown at program start. Showing and hiding dynamically works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo on the layout result2 near the visibility tag :

```
android:orientation="vertical"enter code here
    android:visibility="gone" >
```

The "enter code here" might prevent the layout to be recompiled and you might be using an old one which has not visibility="gone" set

Answer (score 0):

Even though you didnt paste your class code, I think, that it is because you have set setContentView method to your R.id.result2. You can not set visibility GONE to a contentView or it would be not too comfortable to use..

It really depends on what you want to actually do with your layouts, but I think that there are better ways to accomplish that

Next thing is that you cannot show the layout again if you set visibility to GONE. Better is to set visibility to INVISIBLE and when you want to shlw it again, just set visibility to VISIBLE. When you call GONE, the view can not be visible anymore.

And yes, it is more comfortable to set it in your class than in xml.

Answer (score -2):

just set `LinearLayout1.VISIBLE(View.INVISIBLE)`
in your class to hide and
 `LinearLayout1.VISIBLE(View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: These are not even valid. You may be thinking `ll.setVisibility()`